# AMP carousel text will be cut off

Tags: overflow, carousel, amp-html

it´s the first time that I´m working with AMP sites. My problem ist that the text under the carousel will be cut off.
I've created a jsbin to show you my problem.

```
[http://jsbin.com/pemimilimi/edit?html,css,js,output][1]
```

Even on the ampbyexample.com it does not work.

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/image_galleries_with_amp-carousel/#dynamic-text-size

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have: `max-height: 30%;` on the .carousel element.

If you remove that, it will take as much space as it needs, but then, it will not look good. My best advice is that you make it scroll with: `overflow: scroll;`

Your CSS for .caption would be:

```
.carousel2 .caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: smaller;
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

This allows you to scroll the text of the caption even when the text is to long (vs just cutting it).